# Has Alexander Pierce ever been the director of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shield

Was Alexander Pierce the director of SHIELD before Nick Fury? In *Captain America* 2 it was mentioned that he made Nick Fury the director of SHIELD, then whether Alexander Pierce himself was the director of SHIELD? He passed the director to Nick Fury, just as Fury later passed to Coulson? If not, who was the director of SHIELD after Peggy Carter retires?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/SHIELDDirectors

Comment: Thank you Valorum, this is useful, could you also provide a list of SHILED directors in MCU please？

Comment: Peggy Carter and Nick Fury. Also Coulson if you consider AoS to be part of the MCU

Comment: Nick Fury is right after Peggy Carter? I always assume that there are many other directors between them.

Comment: I was under the impression Pierce had been head of SHIELD but after some looking around I don’t think he ever was. No time to write an answer up now though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that Pierce was never director (or at least he was never mentioned to be director in any MCU or related work), and that Fury's predecessor was R. Keller (as seen in Captain Marvel).

The known directors from the MCU, Agent Carter and Agents of SHIELD are:

- Peggy Carter (founding director)
- R. Keller
- Nick Fury
- Phillip Coulson
- Jeffrey Mace
- Daisy Johnson (acting in place of Coulson)
- Alphonso Mackenzie (current)

Also, Deke Shaw (alternate timeline).

Source: [ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/mcu-every-character-director-of-shield/)

Comment: I ignored Keller because he did not act like a director in Captain Marvel, and I did not notice any clues that could prove that he was the director at the time, but marvel wiki says he was. Thank you.

Comment: Weren't there several people above Coulson during the first few seasons of AoS?  Or were they some other rank above Director?  They were mostly only seen at HQ, not acting in the field.  I'm thinking in particular of that woman with the pink streak in her hair, forgot her name...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Fury is director for Season 1, until AoS catches up with Winter Soldier. Fury appoints Coulson to replace him as director at the conclusion of the season.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: The woman with the pink streak in her hair was [Agent Victoria Hand](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Victoria_Hand), but she and Coulson were at the same level. I think the only people at higher levels were [Director Nick Fury](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nick_Fury) and [Deputy Director Maria Hill](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Maria_Hill).

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Pierce was a politician, he was the Secretary of the World Security Council

His job was to oversee the running of SHIELD, part of this involved appointing a director

For a real world equivalent see the [NSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_of_the_National_Security_Agency) where the director is nominated by the president and votedd on by he senate